# Receiving of the URL scheme of the mobile app in JS

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I'm trying to get the URL scheme of my mobile app in browser. Then when I click on some button, it should redirect back to the mobile app.

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<activity
      android:launchMode="singleTop"
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="my.app" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I tried this approach, but `document.referrer` is always empty:

```js
const link = document.referrer;

window.location.replace(link);
```

Is it possible to dynamically get URL scheme of the app in JS or I need to know it?

**UPD:** Guys, if you have any advices, I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried app links/deep links?

Comment: @SarahKhan Yes, I know about them. But can they help me to get the url scheme of my app (in my case, "my.app") in javascript and save in the variable? Or I need to know a scheme?